# Flutter: Animation to start automatically when page loads

Tags: flutter, animation, ripple

just wondering if someone can help me out here.  I did try to solve this myself but I am new to Flutter and can seem to get this going.  I have some Flutter code (as per the link below) that creates a page with ripple animation. It's almost perfect for what I am trying to do BUT, the animation is activated from a floatingActionButton that the user needs to press.  Could somebody PLEASE alter this code so that the animation just runs automatically when the page loads?  I tried...  I really did but I couldnt get this going.  I also looked at other examples but couldnt blend it all together.

This is the code:
https://gist.github.com/MarcinusX/6925808a813e1067c52539068c9978f2

Cheers and thanks in advance everyone...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full working example for what you wanted. I threw it together quickly so it may not be the best solution. But basically what's happening is it's using a simple `bool` value set to `false` at the beginning -

Then once the animation triggers, it sets it back to false. I added in a timer as well so it's not as jarring for a user, and hopefully it'll make it easier for them to understand where they are in the user interface. You can remove it if you don't like it however.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rect_getter/rect_getter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fab overlay transition',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final Duration animationDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 300);
  final Duration delay = Duration(milliseconds: 300);
  GlobalKey rectGetterKey = RectGetter.createGlobalKey();
  Rect rect;

  // Handle time
  Timer timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // Timer starts here, this is called before the widget tree is built
    timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () => setState(() {}));
    super.initState();
  }

  // Disposes of timer - this ensures the timer is properly cancelled when this page is pulled from the widget tree
  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (timer != null) timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }


  // This makes sure the animation only runs once
  bool onTapHandler = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // I moved your functions down here but it doesn't matter where they go in this case I don't think
    void _goToNextPage() {
      Navigator.of(context).push(FadeRouteBuilder(page: NewPage())).then((_) => setState(() => rect = null));
    }

    void onTap() async {
      setState(() => rect = RectGetter.getRectFromKey(rectGetterKey));

      if (rect != null)
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          setState(() => rect = rect.inflate(1.3 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.longestSide));
          Future.delayed(animationDuration + delay, _goToNextPage);
        });
    }

    /// Here is where the magic happens
    /// This makes sure both the timer is finished and the that the flag hasn't 
    /// been tripped yet. After the [onTapHandler] is set to true it won't run again
    if (!timer.isActive && !onTapHandler) {
      onTap();
      onTapHandler = true;
    }

    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Fab overlay transition')),
          body: Center(child: Text('This is first page')),
          floatingActionButton: RectGetter(
            key: rectGetterKey,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: onTap,
              child: Icon(Icons.mail_outline),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        _ripple(),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _ripple() {
    if (rect == null) {
      return Container();
    }
    return AnimatedPositioned(
      duration: animationDuration,
      left: rect.left,
      right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - rect.right,
      top: rect.top,
      bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - rect.bottom,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FadeRouteBuilder<T> extends PageRouteBuilder<T> {
  final Widget page;

  FadeRouteBuilder({@required this.page})
      : super(
          pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) => page,
          transitionsBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2, child) {
            return FadeTransition(opacity: animation1, child: child);
          },
        );
}

class NewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('NewPage'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Ty.  I'm blown away that you did this.  I'm working hard to mash it into my project and have hit one little snag.  This splash animation sets itself as the home page.  In my project, I already have a homepage, with my splash screen being generated on a different screen (.dart file).  I'm trying to change that so that its not the home screen as this is causing any buttons I have to go back ot the splash screen where I use '/' for the navigator.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to pull the homepage attribute out of the splash screen and have as an ordinary page.  Now, please understand that I am very new to programming so my thought process and terminology is probably pretty bad.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I fully understand but I'd maybe look at _goToNextPage()

As this is the only function making a route change I believe.



I suggest you watch this tutorial series. It will help you with the basics of Flutter :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ukSR1GRtMU&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jLYyp2Aoh6hcWuxFDX6PBJ

Comment: Thanks Ty, I will definately check out the vid.  I am completely new and I have been cobbling code together, hoping that it will all work with a bit of fudging around.  I definately need to go back to basics...

Comment: No worries! I totally understand. I was there once too. If you take the time to learn the basics you'll start to breeze through this kind of stuff.

I would really recommend learning how to pass state through your app after learning the basics. A lot of people, including myself use the Business Logic Component method of managing state, I love it, but that's just me!

Comment: Also, sorry Vincent, but just a reminder, if you found the answer to be useful please upvote it :)